Handle Secret Zero Challenge using HashiCorp Vault Approle Authentication and Terraform (Trusted Entity)
So I'm trying to figure out how to properly hide my application secrets once deployed in production and found out about Secret Management System and settled with HashiCorp Vault. I am able to successfully hide secrets and retrieve them using VaultSharp. Now my problem is the so called Secret Zero Challenge. My implementation will be all on premise, thus AWS and the like are out of scope. And I think Terraform with the help of Vault Agent might do the job? There's a sample code from HashiCorp repo but I have no idea and haven't found any comprehensive guides online on how to setup the Trusted Orchestrator and response wrapping that was mentioned from the sample code.
I am hosting my vault server in an Ubuntu Server and plans to deploy the application in a separate VM.
Thank you in advance.

Unfortunately none of those will probably solve your Secret Zero, and solving it depends greatly upon your environment, and so you probably need to describe the environment in much greater detail to a Vault expert who can then advise accordingly. If this was e.g. AWS then an IAM instance profile could potentially solve this, but you stated this is on-prem.

@MatthewSchuchard as what I've expected, there are also few options I've thought about, like making the vault server push/send the generated token by vault agent to application server, etc. Then again, I have to consider a lot of security related things. So instead, I've opted to expose an endpoint from my application where I will manually input the credentials, this may be manual but I think it is the most bulletproof solution in my case. Thank you.
